# ANTLR parses greedily even though it can match high priority rule

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am using the following ANTLR grammar to define a function.

```
definition_function
    : DEFINE FUNCTION function_name '[' language_name ']'
      RETURN attribute_type '{' function_body '}'
    ;

function_name
    : id
    ;

language_name
    : id
    ;

function_body
    : SCRIPT
    ;

SCRIPT
    :   '{' ('\u0020'..'\u007e' | ~( '{' | '}' ) )* '}' 
        { setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length()-1)); }
    ;
```

But when I try to parse two functions like below,

```
define function concat[Scala] return string {
  var concatenatedString = ""
  for(i <- 0 until data.length) {
     concatenatedString += data(i).toString
  }
  concatenatedString
};
define function concat[JavaScript] return string {
  var str1 = data[0];
  var str2 = data[1];
  var str3 = data[2];
  var res = str1.concat(str2,str3);
  return res;
};
```

Then ANTLR doesn't parse this like two function definitions, but like a single function with the following body,

```
  var concatenatedString = ""
  for(i <- 0 until data.length) {
     concatenatedString += data(i).toString
  }
  concatenatedString
};
define function concat[JavaScript] return string {
  var str1 = data[0];
  var str2 = data[1];
  var str3 = data[2];
  var res = str1.concat(str2,str3);
  return res;
```

Can you explain this behavior? The body of the function can have anything in it. How can I correctly define this grammar?

Answer (score 3):

Your rule matches that much because `'\u0020'..'\u007e'` from the rule `'{' ('\u0020'..'\u007e' | ~( '{' | '}' ) )* '}'` matches both `{` and `}`.

Your rule should work if you define it like this:

```
SCRIPT
    :   '{' ( SCRIPT | ~( '{' | '}' ) )* '}' 
    ;
```

However, this will fail when the script block contains, says, strings or comments that contain `{` or `}`. Here is a way to match a `SCRIPT` token, including comments and string literals that could contain `{` and '}':

```
SCRIPT
 : '{' SCRIPT_ATOM* '}'
 ;

fragment SCRIPT_ATOM
 : ~[{}]
 | '"' ~["]* '"'
 | '//' ~[\r\n]*
 | SCRIPT
 ;
```

A complete grammar that properly parses your input would then look like this:

```
grammar T;

parse
 : definition_function* EOF
 ;

definition_function
 : DEFINE FUNCTION function_name '[' language_name ']' RETURN attribute_type SCRIPT ';'
 ;

function_name
 : ID
 ;

language_name
 : ID
 ;

attribute_type
 : ID
 ;

DEFINE
 : 'define'
 ;

FUNCTION
 : 'function'
 ;

RETURN
 : 'return'
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

SCRIPT
 : '{' SCRIPT_ATOM* '}'
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
 ;

fragment SCRIPT_ATOM
 : ~[{}]
 | '"' ~["]* '"'
 | '//' ~[\r\n]*
 | SCRIPT
 ;
```

which also parses the following input properly:

```
define function concat[JavaScript] return string {
  for (;;) { 
    while (true) { } 
  }
  var s = "}"
  // }
  return s 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely need SCRIPT to be a token (recognized by a *lexer* rule), you can use a *parser* rule which recognizes nested blocks (the **block** rule below). The grammar included here should parse your example as two distinct function definitions.

```
DEFINE : 'define';
FUNCTION : 'function';
RETURN : 'return';
ID : [A-Za-z]+;
ANY : . ;
WS : [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip ;

test : definition_function* ;

definition_function
    : DEFINE FUNCTION function_name '[' language_name ']'
      RETURN attribute_type block ';'
    ;

function_name : id ;
language_name : id ;
attribute_type : 'string' ;
id : ID;

block
    : '{' ( ( ~('{'|'}') )+ | block)* '}'
    ;
```

Comment: Note that lexer rules can also contain recursive (lexer) rules. Note that inside a parser rule `~('{'|'}')` does *not* match **any char** other that `{` and `}`, but rather, **any token** other than the tokens that match `{` and `}`.